# How can I write a trigger that can subtract values between two tables

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have a table called transaction that has these fields

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    transaction_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    status varchar(255),
    myPIN varchar(255),
    amount_paid varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Another table called defaulters that has the following

```
CREATE TABLE defaulters (
    defaulters_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    myPIN varchar(255),
    debt_amount varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (defaulters_id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now I want the value to subtract if the value of `status=1` in transaction table where `myPIN` is equal to the `amount_paid` then it subtract `debt_amount-amount_paid` to get `debt_amount` remain 
 and it reflect the remaining amount in `defaulters` table in `debt_amount` field.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fad59e92e22ba1b82259b39a1dbf1332)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
ON transaction 
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE defaulters 
SET debt_amount = debt_amount - NEW.amount_paid
WHERE myPIN = NEW.myPIN
  AND NEW.status = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=daae611286a9a0def202d87817380cd2)